# CMake can't find ONNX RUNTIME LIB when I try to compile onnx model which is converted from pytorch

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I am trying to run the onnx model which is converted from pytorch in C++.
but when I try to compile ONNX model in C++, It fails with the error shown below text.

> CMake Error : The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files : ONNX_RUNTIME_LIB liked by target "ObjectDetectionInferende" in directory /hyeonseop/OD/test/onnx_od

I think CMake couldn't find the onnx runtime library.

my cmake code is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(ObjectDetectionInference)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

find_path(ONNX_RUNTIME_SESSION_INCLUDE_DIRS onnxruntime_cxx_api.h HINTS "/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0/include")
find_library(ONNX_RUNTIME_LIB lib HINTS "/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp helper.cpp)

add_executable(ObjectDetectionInference ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(ObjectDetectionInference PRIVATE ${ONNX_RUNTIME_SESSION_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
target_link_libraries(ObjectDetectionInference PRIVATE ${ONNX_RUNTIME_LIB}) # ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
```

and My path is

> root@4fe7a1a9f82d:/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0# ls

> GIT_COMMIT_ID  LICENSE  Privacy.md  README.md  ThirdPartyNotices.txt
> VERSION_NUMBER  include  lib

> root@4fe7a1a9f82d:/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0# pwd

> /hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0

I think there's no wrong.
How can I solve it?
Should I install onnx and onnx runtime again? nor It's occured because of dependencies or version?

Comment: My advice is to put `REQUIRED` in your find_libary() and find_package() so that it errors out when they are not found. In this case it looks like `find_library(ONNX_RUNTIME_LIB lib HINTS "/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0")` failed to find a library named `lib` in the folder `/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0` Are you sure that that is the file name instead of onnxruntime or something more descriptive?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, when I type 'ls' in the directory, it is shown. I'll try REQUIRED.

Comment: So there is a file in that folder `/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0` is named `lib.a` or `lib.so`? or `liblib.a` it's not asking for a folder name here. `/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0` is the folder name.

Comment: Doesn't 'lib' mean the folder? when I type 'ls' in 'lib' folder,  root@4fe7a1a9f82d:/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0/lib# ls
 libonnxruntime.so         libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so     libonnxruntime_providers_tensorrt.so
libonnxruntime.so.1.17.0  libonnxruntime_providers_shared.so

Comment: find_library() is on your OS is used to find an individual  `.a` or `.so` file. It's not to find a folder name. You are giving it the folder name instead of the library file name.

Comment: `HINTS "/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0"` probably should be `HINTS "/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0/lib"` and the filename instead of `lib` should be `onnxruntime` or similar depending on what files you have in that lib folder.

Comment: It's working with `find_library(ONNX_RUNTIME_LIB onnxruntime HINTS "/hyeonseop/OD/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.17.0/lib")` Thank you so so much. I was too stupid. I struggled with this whole day but you save me! but I don't have just 'onnxruntime' in the lib folder. why does it work?

Comment: There may be other libs in that folder. I am not familiar with the onnxruntime library. I am commenting because I have used CMake at work since 2008.

Comment: Okay, Sincerely appreciate with you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Your welcome, I am glad I was able to help.